# jQuery .load with variable as url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

I'm trying to load an external php file/widget into another php file via a jQuery-constructed mobile menu bar. The menu bar is `<div class="slicknav_menu">` called in the code below. On the front-end I can see the variable loading the blog url okay, but `pluginDir` doesn't seem to load it in the `$` function.

I'm still getting a hang on proper syntax. What am I doing wrong? Does `.load` accept variables?

```
var pluginDir = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>";

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1030) {
    $(".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir + '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php');
}
```

Comment: `$(".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir + '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php');`. In javascript `+` is the concatenation operator for string

Comment: its acutally `+` in javascript, `.` is concatenation in PHP

Comment: I actually tried `+` as well, but it doesn't seem to be working either. I'll update it above to show my syntax.

Comment: what does `bloginfo` do anyway? returns a `string`? you might need some `echo` there

Comment: `bloginfo` grabs the url of my site, which i'm concatenating to the exact php file path. I realize it's an odd way of going about it, but it's an existing jQuery mobile menu that I need to load my php plugin into only when the viewport is below 1030px.

Comment: @Ignaus The string will not contain `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` as it will be processed by PHP, which will depending on what bloginfo does, either output a string or output nothing at all since there is no `echo`.

Comment: I guess my question is part of a much larger one: What's the best way to load a php file into a jQuery-constructed `div`, using only jQuery, but needing php(Wordpress) functions for the urls? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ignaus I disagree, it will definitely run since the quotes are not themselves enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: And @Ignaus & @thebreiflabb, `<?php blog_info('url'); ?>` is loading into the variable correctly, so I'm assuming it would load into the function too, but it's not...

Comment: Take a look here: http://dev.paper-art.co/product/test-product-one/  It's the last script in the `head`.

Comment: When the browser is below 1030px the .slicknav_menu displays, and I need to load the cart widget that's in the top-right of the page normally into that .slicknav_menu div.

Comment: @dmoz Your problem is not with the plguinDir variable, rather `$` is undefined, try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Can I just use jQuery to load the php function that I'm using when the browser is above 1030px, rather than loading the php file?

Comment: `slicknav_menu` has `display:none`

Comment: @dmoz In this case you should probably just output both of them all the time, and use CSS media-queries to show/hide either one depending on screen-width. Then you don't have to load stuff via AJAX later on.

Comment: @Ignaus, you need to resize your browser to see it.

Comment: @thebreiflabb, that's a good call. But it's still not loading anyways without the viewport conditional.

Comment: @dmoz You have removed the quotes now, which gives syntax error. At the `pluginDir` string.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying that from before. Try now.

Comment: The CSS is doing that now, but the actual cart link isn't loading into .slicknav_menu, right?

Comment: It's probably because it is run instantly, before the element is in the DOM. Wait for dom ready `jQuery(function() {/*code here */});` Also your cart-dropdown.php produces a 500 internal server error which you will have to fix first. Don't forget `jQuery` in front of `(".slicknav_menu")`

Comment: Liiiike this? (Sorry, jQuery syntax still not totally my thing): `jQuery(function() {
 (".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir+"/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php");
 });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74157/discussion-between-thebreiflabb-and-dmoz).

Comment: @thebreiflabb If you'd like to post an answer to the initial question, i'll accept it so others can benefit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no element with class `slicknav_menu` at the time of `load` being called. And `jQuery` ran `noConflict()` setting `$` back to undefined, making it not even try to load at all.

By moving `$(".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir + '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php');` after the element is added to the DOM, and using `jQuery` in place of `$`, it will load properly.

Taking only relevant parts of the original source code, gives the solution:

```
var pluginDir = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>";

jQuery('#menu-main-menu').slicknav();
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1030) {
    jQuery(".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir + '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it brought to light some additional issues, @thebreiflabb helped tremendously with, and basically answered, the original question. So I'll consider it closed via the comments.